# Is there a proper way to tell if a DOM element is tied to a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say a custom event listener outside of the React eco-system fires when tapping an element and you would like to know if the target element is controlled by React.

I've noticed that React DOM elements have two properties which look similar to this(characters at the end vary):

`__reactEventHandlers$e1mb3sp9ly`

`__reactInternalInstance$e1mb3sp9ly`

Is it OK to use their presents as an indicator that the DOM element is controlled by React or is there a better way? Or is this not supported?

Comment: If you have the reference of your react app container(on which you have called ReactDoM.render), then you can check rootElement.contains(elementToTest), I believe anything under the root element will be controlled by react

Comment: In this case I don't have a reference to the react app container.

Comment: It must have some id(generally `root`), you can call getElementById to get its reference